# A Lemma Leading to fundamental theorem of calculus of variation uses fixed function. What are their properties?

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, analysis, calculus-of-variations

I am currently reading Calculus of Variations by I.M Gelfand and S. V. Fomin.

One of the lemmas in the book states

If $\alpha(x)$ is continuous in $[a,b]$, and if

$$\int_a^b \alpha(x)h'(x)=0$$

for every function $h(x)\in \mathcal{D}_1(a,b)$ such that $h(a)=h(b)=0$, then $\alpha(x)=c$ for all $x$ in $[a,b]$, where $c$ is a constant

Now $\mathcal{D}_1(a,b)$ they define as a normed linear space and $\alpha(x)$ as a fixed function

In the proof they define $h(x) = \int_a^x [\alpha(\xi)-x]d\xi$ $(1)$ so that $h(x)$ belongs to $\mathcal{D}_1(a,b)$ and use this later to derive the result
$$\int_a^b [\alpha(x)-c]h'(x)dx = \int_a^b [\alpha(x)-c]^2dx$$

My Question:

Does this mean since $\alpha(x)$ is a "fixed function" that $(1)$ can be expressed as
$$h(x) = \int_a^x [\alpha(\xi)-x]d\xi = (\alpha(x)-c)x-(\alpha(a)-c)a$$
Which would make its derivative
$$h'(x) = \alpha(x)-c$$
Which is what we need to derive the above result on the proof

Additional Question:

1. Does this mean that fixed functions can be treated as a constant would be in normal calculus
2. If so do we only substitute the limits of the integral into them when working with integrals
3. Finally where can I find a better definition of them or am I just miss interpreting the nomenclature